# Bootstrap multiple rows based on mysql query count

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to create a row of 6 colunm images.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $sql = //my query
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
       <img id="img" class="img-responsive" src="img/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Which works fine when there is only 6 rows from the database, however when there is 7 the extra one gets bumped to the far right rather than the far left on the next row, see example below.

```
| img | img | img | img | img | img
                              | img
```

Normal result i am looking for would be

```
| img | img | img | img | img | img
| img
```

I want to create a new bootstrap row after every 6 results, any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch all the values into an array first, count how many elements are in the array and then dynamically control what span classes you use.

```
<div class="row">
<?php
$sql = //my query
$images = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $images[] = $row['image'];
}
$column_class = count($images) > 6 ?  "col-xs-3 col-md-1" : "col-xs-6 col-md-2";

foreach ($images as $image) {
?>
<div class="<?= $column_class ?>">
   <img id="img" class="img-responsive" src="img/<?= $image ?>" />
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I have other values from the database connected to that image that i need though, with this example i would only have access to the image column.

Comment: Ah true, you could refactor it to store the whole $row variable.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this before when the heights of the images are not identical.  the float left only floats to the point where the bottom line is uneven.  try adding a style height with a reasonable fixed height.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $sql = //my query
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
       <img id="img" class="img-responsive" style="height:100px" src="img/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: That does work but it breaks the responsiveness of the images

Comment: good - so it was height.  now you just need a responsive image solution that adjusts the width to match the fixed height.  responsive images are tricky for this reason.  that's beyond the scope of your initial question.  but here is one good article on the subject: https://css-tricks.com/crop-top/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in a recent project and was able to solve it with this code. I only have two views so I only need the two lines but you could have more if you wanted. You can see this in action on this [page](https://capebeads.storeswarm.com/portfolio)

```
<div class="visible-md-block visible-lg-block clearfix">

<div class="visible-sm-block visible-xs-block clearfix">
```

Here is the full php code for the gallery page

```
<?php
    $c = 1;
    foreach($images as $image) {?>
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
       <a class="thumbnail" href="path to full size image" data-toggle="lightbox" data-footer="<?php echo $image['caption']; ?>">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="path to thumbnail" alt="...">
      </a>
     </div>
<?php
        if(($c % 4) == 0) {
            echo '<div class="visible-md-block visible-lg-block clearfix"></div>';
        }

        if(($c % 3) == 0) {
            echo '<div class="visible-sm-block visible-xs-block clearfix"></div>';
        }

        $c++;
    }
?>
```

Sorry while this code works for when you want the number of images in a row to change at different screen sizes I just re read your question and you say you just want 6 across all the time so you could just use one line

```
if(($c % 6) == 0) {
            echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        }
```

The $c variable is just a counter and the code $c % 6 == 0 will put the clearfix div every time $c is divisible by 6.